# Is 8GB of RAM enough to run Android Studio emulator?

Tags: android-studio

I've bought an Acer Aspire 5 laptop that unfortunately comes with 4GB of RAM solded. I can't upgrade to 16GB of RAM since there are no 12GB RAM chips. I've bought 8GB before discovering this (trying to install the 8GB of RAM lead to the discovery of solded 4GB of RAM).

Firefox on Debian 12 with a few tabs opened eats ~4GB of RAM so I would be left with ~8GB of RAM to run Android Studio + Emulator.

Do you think this will cut it or will I be running out of memory?

Asking since I'd like to return the memory chip if it fails to improve my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will, Android studio could run on 4gb ram, as my former laptop ran it on 4GB ram. However, it was quite slow, and lagged a lot.

[image: Here is a snapshot of how much ram android studio uses while idle]

Comment: This is with the emulator?

Comment: No, but it would run it with an emulator

Comment: I did a test and with 12GB the system didn't pass 60% RAM usage, overall. I could run the emulator with two Pixel phones. Though it's a bit slow to install the application on the emulator and run it, it does the job. I guess this is due to my Intel i5 core processor.